# MS Access Modern Charts - VBA adding trendline

Tags: vba, charts, ms-access-2013

I would like to use VBA to format MS access modern charts in forms, for example adding a trendline, turning on data labels etc. I have searched but cannot see any methods or data structures to do this. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

This may give you what you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QADS5XxVIs&ab_channel=Microsoft365

Keep in mind...Access is a NOT a great tool for creating charts. As an alternative, you may want to import your data into MS Excel, from Access, and create your Trend Line in Excel. There are so many ways to move data between Access and Excel, back and forth, so if you get stuck with one app, just switch to the other app!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim var As ChartSeries
    For Each var In Me!Chart40.ChartSeriesCollection
    ' show data labels    
    var.DisplayDataLabel = True
    ' change Ling weight 
    var.LineWeight = 50000
    ' add trendline    
'0;'None'
'1;'Linear'
'2;'Exponential'
'3;'Logarithmic'
'4;'Polynomial'
'5;'Power'
'6;'MovingAverage'
        ChartSeriesTrendlineOptions = 1
    Next
Me.Chart40.Requery
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).